# How can I add a security policy file to a gradle build for an rmi application?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, rmi, java-security-manager

Can anyone tell me how I can add the java command `"-Djava.security.policy=mysecurity.policy"` to a `gradle` build for a `java rmi` application. Thanks.

This is the error I get when I run gradle run

> gradle run
>
> Task :run 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
>           at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
>           at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)
>           at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:147)
>           at identityserver.server.IdServer.setupServer(IdServer.java:73)
>           at identityserver.server.IdServer.main(IdServer.java:32)
>   <<<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [13s]
>
> :run

//Gradle build file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'identityserver.server.IdServer'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4"
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-gradle'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

sourceSets{
    main.java.srcDirs = ["src/identityserver/server", "src/identityserver/client"]
}
```

//Java rmi server class, with security manager set

```
package identityserver.server;
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class IdServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerOperations{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5057719935941913677L;
    private static int registryPort = 1099;
    private Options options;
    private String[] args;
    private String name;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        IdServer idServer = null;
        try {
            idServer = new IdServer(args,"//IdServer");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("IdServer err: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (args.length > 3){
            idServer.usage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        idServer.parse();
        idServer.setupServer(idServer);
    }

    public IdServer(String[] args, String name) throws RemoteException{
        super();
        this.args = args;
        this.name = name;
        options = new Options();

        options.addOption("p","port",true, "port number");
        options.addOption("v", "verbose",false, "print detailed messages");

    }

    public void parse(){
        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

        CommandLine cmd = null;
        try {
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);

            if (cmd.hasOption("p")){
                System.out.println("Have port number " + cmd.getOptionValue("p"));

            }else if (cmd.hasOption("v")){
                System.out.println("Verbose!!!!");
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
            usage();
        }
    }

    private void usage(){
        System.err.println("Usage: java IdServer [--port <port#>][--verbose]");
    }

    public void setupServer(IdServer idServer){
        try {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(registryPort);
            registry.rebind("IdServer", idServer);
            System.out.println("IdServer bound in registry");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String createAccount(String loginName) throws RemoteException {
        return "Account created without password";
    }

    @Override
    public String createAccount(String loginName, String realName, String password) throws RemoteException {
        return "Account created with password";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a security manager?

Answer (score 2):

You can add jvm properties to your test configuration

```
test {
  systemProperties 'java.security.policy': file("$projectDir/mysecurity.policy").absolutePath
}
```